# Как отредактировать фразу и избежать скобок?

Tags: окончания, оформление-текста

*Нам кажется, что это тот (та) единственный(-ая) и неповторимый(-ая), о котором(-ой) мы мечтали всю жизнь.*

Мне всё это нагромождение скобок и окончаний представляется лишним: выглядит как какой-то документ или бланк. Но всё же хотелось бы узнать, правильно ли оформлены эти "добавки"? Я не нашёл официального подтверждения, только мнения в чате Грамоты.

И ещё. Если автор подобного предложения хочет отметить не только мужской род, но и женский, как тогда написать его "красивее"?

Comment: Средний род надо бы учесть. Куда красивше будет.